# How can I put my random values into an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, selection

I'm making a program that uses selection sort on a set of integers, but I'm making it better by allowing the user to ask how many integers they want to be sorted, and if they want to input the integers or want the integers randomly generated. I've coded the program to be able to generate the random integers so far, but I haven't gotten to the user being able to generate their own numbers.

How am I able to take those randomly generated numbers, and put them into an array so that I can use Selection sort on those values?

```
package sortingexcersices;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortingExcersices {

    public static int myarray[], numOfElements, arrValues, n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many integers do you want to sort?");
        numOfElements = in.nextInt();

        myarray = new int[numOfElements];

        boolean found = false;

        do {

            System.out.println("If you would like random numbers, press 1.");
            System.out.println("If you would like to generate your own numbers, press 2.");

            n = in.nextInt();

            if (n == 1) {
                found = true;
            } else if (n == 2) {
                found = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your input was invalid.");
            }

        } while (n != 1 && n != 2);

        if (found = true) {
            Random values = new Random();

            for (int i = 1; i <= myarray.length; i++) {
                arrValues = 1 + values.nextInt(50);
                System.out.print(arrValues + " ,");


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-indexed in Java... your for loop should start at `int i = 0`. Then you can just assign the values:

```
Random values = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    myarray[i] = values.nextInt(50);
}
```

Sorting is then achieved by calling `Arrays.sort(myarray)` or by implementing a custom sorting function if necessary.

Comment: When i do this, i get an error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at sortingexcersices.SortingExcersices.main(SortingExcersices.java:42)
0 ,0 ,0 ,Java Result: 1

Comment: Are your sure that you changed the `<=` to a `<`? ;)

Comment: Sorry haha youre right, but when i do that i only get arraylength amount of 0s, not random numbers

Comment: Perhaps you need to include a check that ensures that the provided `numOfElements` is greater than `0`.

Comment: ... which boils down to what I wrote a minute before him, only that I did not include syntax errors. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
 myarray[i] = 1 + values.nextInt(50);
 System.out.print(myarray[i] + " ,");
}
```

Comment: When doing this, i get error 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at sortingexcersices.SortingExcersices.main(SortingExcersices.java:42)
0 ,0 ,0 ,Java Result: 1

Comment: the empty brackets in myarray.length() give me an error, once i remove them i get 1 less value then i wanted (if i asked for 5 integers, it gives me 4)

Comment: You don't want the -1, the < takes care of the index difference.

Comment: Yeah I got really confused. I checked it. You don't need the `-1` and the `()` are wrong at the length

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= myarray.length; i++) {
    arrValues[i] = 1 + values.nextInt(50); //you have to add the position
    System.out.print(arrValues + " ,");
}
```